Query Optimization on Google BigQuery on a large dataset
I got a dataset with 13 millions of rows and many columns, if I take just 3 columns in my select, I get 300 MB to analyze the dataset with a single easy query (just like select x,y,z from 'c' where x>n (so I don't think it can be optimized that much, I can't use btw materialized view because I got some functions which are not supported), I can use WHERE condition but it doesn't change the volume of the elaboration.
This dataset is continuously updating.
Is there any work around I can do for decreasing the volume of the query (maybe decreasing number of rows/columns of my dataset in another way, like not with a Query) also having my dataset updating day by day?

Take a look in partitioned tables and clusteting.
